# Is there a database data browser app that will automatically compose views based on foreign keys?

Tags: sql, database, scaffolding

Every now and then when I'm browsing data in a database, I get tired of writing ad-hoc queries to join in the various tables I want to see, and I go looking for an app that will:

- Allow me to follow foreign key relationships
- Automatically display tables in a tree-like format based on relationships
- Compose views by automatically joining on foreign keys

I know this can be done because I wrote (and lost) such an app many years ago, but I can't seem to find anything out there. The closest I've seen is generated "scaffolding" such as RoR and MS Dynamic Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the "Data Browser" included in the tool [Jailer](http://jailer.sourceforge.net) ([Screenshots](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jailer/)). It allows you to navigate through the database based on relationships.

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind, but after 2 years, I guess this is by default the correct answer :)